# How to make a DL price prediction model aware of market fluctuations

Tags: regression, neural-networks, trend

here's a pretty general question, so i do not expect to get precise answers. Instead i hope to read ideas and suggestions.

I have a deployied proprietary Deep Learning model that make retail price prediction of pre-owned cars.
Data are shaped like this: car characteristics, selling date and selling price and i'm receiving updated data every other day.
The model makes a preliminary clustering phase to restrict the proper training to already pretty sililar car. Cannot share the proper architecture, sorry.

Problem is: the model seems not to react to market fluctuations in average selling price, i.e. the MAE and PMAE are getting worst during and immediately after trending phases.

I'm aware that a NN is most probably not the best choice for this kind of tasks, but the client wants to stick with his beloved model.

The model is being re-trained every sunday on new datas and the best model based on MAE is being deployed.

What you guys would try to enhance the model awareness of trends?

**[Update]**

We are running some experiments and there is a pretty promising one. Our model got linearly time-dependent weights: newest data (recently sold cars) got are taking an higher training weight w/r to older. We switched to **exponential weights** instead and the model seems to be more efficently and more promptly aware of the market trends. The current solution we are testing is an adaptive one: pooling a linear and and exponential model and take the most accurate, agnostically with respect to the market trends.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This is an interesting question that I hope gets a quality answer. However, in response to your comments that you believe your client’s beloved deep learning model isn’t a great choice for this kind of work, part of your job as a consultant is to tell the client when they’re wrong.

Comment: Hi Dave, i agree with you 100% but of course (and sadly) it is more complex than this.